# React JS test case for componentWillMount(), testing asynchronously API call

Tags: reactjs, testing, tdd

I am trying to write a test case for the below code,

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { userProfile: {} };
  }
  async componentWillMount() {
    const res = await fetch('/api/getUserDetails');
    console.log('App.jsx: RES- Result: ', res);
    let userProfile = await res.json();

    console.log('App.jsx: userProfile- Result: ', userProfile);

    userProfile = mapApiObjectToModel(userProfile);

    this.setState({ userProfile });
  }
}
```

mapApiObjectToModel:

```
import React from 'react';

export const mapApiObjectToModel = inputObj => {
  const outputObj = {};
  const authorizedRoles = ['Admin'];

  if (inputObj) {
    outputObj.fullName = '';

    if (inputObj.data) {
      outputObj.fullName = inputObj.data.data;
    }

    outputObj.role = 'Admin';
    outputObj.isAuthorized = authorizedRoles.includes(outputObj.role);
  }
  console.log('outputObj', outputObj);
  return outputObj;
};
```

res:
Res: body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: ""
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:7000/api/getUserDetails"
**proto**: Response

userProfile:

data: {firstName: "Admin", groupName: "ROLE_ADMIN"}
status: "SUCCESS"
**proto**: Object

I have tried multiple approaches from the internet, nothing seem to work. hence didn't post the code I wrote.

Any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: What testing framework you are using? Are you looking for unit testing or integration testing or e2e testing?

Comment: try changing `this.setState({ userProfile });` to `this.setState({ ...userProfile });` or you can use `this.setState({ userProfile: userProfile});` - see if this works for you.